# PostgreSQL: Shadow Table

Tags: postgresql, web2py

I am using Web2Py smart grid to show the content on the Web.

Since in the database there are some duplicated entries and I would like to hide it some the web. Which I believe there is no way to configure the smart grid. I would need to create a shadow table, which the duplicated entries are removed, for that table.

However I would like to use the shadow table as a subset of the original table - all modification will be made on the original table. And the shadow table provide a view for the original table. But unfortunately the shadow table doesn't work in this way.

How could I make the shadow table effectively get a subset of the original table? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you are describing sounds like Postgres' concept of a [`VIEW`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createview.html)

Comment: Do you want to be able to edit records listed in the grid? If so, how do you decide which of several duplicate entries gets edited?

Answer (score 1):

`distinct` eliminates duplicates

```
create view my_view as
select distinct *
from t

select *
from my_view
```